# Cutting a area from a circle in Sketch 3

Tags: layers, shapes, path, sketch-app

I am having trouble on editing a specific arc from a circle.
Here is what I have, which is a circle.

[image]

I want it to look like this, how can I accomplish it?

[image]

These are my 2 shapes.

[image]

When I subtract them, this is what happens.

[image]

PS. If I my question was too broad, please forgive me. This my first time asking a question.

Comment: Hi SlickCoder, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you have updates your question, please [edit] them in, do **not** use the answer field. We are a Q&A site, not a forum and are rather precise about that :). If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This can be done with shapes by applying Layers > Convert to Outlines on the oval. From there, you can use subtract to get the intended result.

Answer (score 14):

You can use scissors to cut part of the circle.

Draw circle, select Edit mode, add two points, press Enter. Part between these two point we can delete later.

[image]

Select Layer -> Paths -> Scissors

[image]

Hover over part of the circle you want to delete, it will be dashed

[image]

Cut it by left mouse click.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Dash and Gap settings to achieve the same result. 
Create a circle. Turn off the fill and set the border to desired thickness. Click on the gear icon on the Borders setting to reveal the dash fields. In the gap, enter the diameter of the circle * PI, 3.14.  Then increase the Dash field number until you have the desired result or you can use math there as well by entering the total number in Gap * percentage you want.

https://goo.gl/B9Pds6

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract a rectangle shape from the circle:

1. create a rectangle
2. place it over the part of the circle you want to cut out
3. resize and rotate the rectangle so that it aligns perfectly with the part of the circle you want to remove
4. select both the rectangle and circle and use the Subtract command

… and you are left with the original circle with the rectangle shape subtracted from it.

You can find out about the Subtract command here in the [Sketch Documentation — Boolean Operations](http://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/04-shapes/2-boolean-operations.html).

Comment: That didn't work for me.